# ghost document appearing on my desktop after opening a Microsoft Office Word

Tags: ms-word, ms-office

After opening a microsoft word document I saw this appear on my screen. After trying to open it I got a messege saying  it cannot be opened because there is a problem with the contents/ the file is corrupted.

[image]

I don't it's some kind of virus, I'm just intrested in knowing why this happens. (also the full name is: ~$w Microsoft Office Word Document (3).docx and the name of the file I opened is: Microsoft Office Word Document (3).docx so what is the ~$w for?)

Comment: Also this file disappears when I close the word document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a temporary file created by Word itself.
Word merges them with your original file on close. Read up on it f.e. here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/211632/description-of-how-word-creates-temporary-files

> A simplified view of the scheme used to save an edited file
>
> `Create temp file                     Create ~wrdxxxx.tmp
>   Write temp file                      Save example data to ~wrdxxxx.tmp
>   Delete original file                 Delete EXAMPLE.DOC
>   Move temp to target name             Move ~wrdxxxx.tmp to Example.doc`